# watir-webdriver checking table size rows and columns count

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am starting the process of converting my WATIR scripts to use WATIR webdriver.
There a couple of table methods I was using in my WATIR scripts to check the size (rows and columns) of a HTML table.

```
myTable.row_count
myTable.column_count
```

These methods don't exist in webdriver so I am looking for a good way of doing the same check.

For rows this seems to give the same result as the row_count method

```
myTable.rows.length
```

For column count of the table I've tried converting the table to an array of strings and getting the length of the first row, but the conversion to the string array is taking a while.

```
myCols = myTable.strings[0].length
```

Can anyone suggest a better/ quicker method of getting the table size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the first row has the correct number of cells:

```
 table.row.cells.length
```

Comment: Thanks that works, I think I use it with table.rows.each to check each row has the same number :)

Comment: I've extended the Watir::Table class at the start of my script so it now contains row_count/column_count methods, so will not have to change all the unit tests.

Comment: what if the first row(usually the header ) has different no of cells?
How can we find the column count then?